# Formatting and writing data

Tags: c++

I will briefly explain the situation and move to the question.

I have app which writes/reads some data to device(card). 
Here is some sample code.

First the user enters hex string, say "`00000000000000000000AABBEEAABBEE`" (This should be 16 bytes).

Now to *write* this data to card it is being converted to byte array.

```
for(int i=0,m=0; i < size; i+=2,m++)
{
        char ch1, ch2;
        ch1=(char)str[i]; // str is hex string
        ch2=(char)str[i+1];
        int dig1, dig2;
        if(isdigit(ch1)) dig1 = ch1 - '0';
        else if(ch1>='A' && ch1<='F') dig1 = ch1 - 'A' + 10;
        else if(ch1>='a' && ch1<='f') dig1 = ch1 - 'a' + 10;
        if(isdigit(ch2)) dig2 = ch2 - '0';
        else if(ch2>='A' && ch2<='F') dig2 = ch2 - 'A' + 10;
        else if(ch2>='a' && ch2<='f') dig2 = ch2 - 'a' + 10;
        array1[m] = (char)(dig1*16 + dig2); // output byte array
}
```

Now, this byte array is sent to the device, easily like this:

```
 unsigned char sendBuff[16];
 for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
      sendBuff[i]=array1[i];
```

And call a send command, say `Send(sendBuff, 16)`;

Reading is also easy, we call `Receive(receiveBuffer);` Now `receiveBuffer` contains byte array that we stored. We convert it back to hex:

```
 for(k=0;k<16;k++)
 {
      data[k*2]=hexval[((receiveBuffer[k]>>4)&0xF)];
      data[(k*2)+1]=hexval[receiveBuffer[k]&0x0F];  
 }
```

And now `data` contains: "`00000000000000000000AABBEEAABBEE`"

Last time I asked similar question people raised suspicion/interest in the byte format used, endianness etc. My question is can you tell what endianness is used above? Or is it some fixed format? Should I expect some endianness problems?

Comment: You've still not told us the essential: what does the device expect?  Until we know what format the data have to be in, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @JamesKanze: smart card expects nothing, is not above post enough to see how I can write a hex string inside and read it back? device just expects some array of bytes. please clarify more what you want to hear from me. this is a mifare card

Comment: Then why are you writing to it?  What is the purpose of writing to the buffer?  You can `memcpy` any POD of 16 bytes or less into the buffer, but what's the purpose.  If it's only for use within your program, there's no reason to write it to a buffer, and if it is for use outside of the program, you and the other party have to agree on a format.

Comment: @JamesKanze: James, I am the "other party" - I write and read data back as I showed in above example. I write in the `sendBuff` because the `Send` function I mentioned above expects a byte array to write it to a card - did I make it clear now?

Comment: No.  If you're the other party, why do you bother with the buffer?  Just keep the number or the string as is.  If you send the buffer to the card, what you put in it has to be what the card expects or understands.

Comment: @JamesKanze: indeed I am just sending this `sendBuff` to card for storage purposes. I want it to store it there. Then I will read it back. do you see now?

Comment: OK.  In that case, you can define whatever format you want.  Or use an existing format, like protocol buffers or XDR.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think I can just `memcpy` string I want to store to the `sendBuff`, and writing int there I think is more easier - I got some suggestions about this on this forum .. what do you think

Comment: If you always know the type last written, and you only write strings and fundamental types, `memcpy` should work for the fundamental types, and copying in the text of the string should work for strings.  If you don't know that type last written, then you'll need some sort of type information as well (and enum value on a byte?).

Comment: @JamesKanze: dear James. This card has different blocks. Usually I know on which block I stored which type of data. Does it answer your question? It seems this card doesn't pay much attention to endianness right? It stores data **in the way** I send it to, e.g., does not change the order.

Comment: Bytes don't have endianness (unless they're transmitted on a serial line, but that doesn't normally concern a programmer).  If the card doesn't access the data, it doesn't matter to the card how it is stored.  Endianness only comes into play when you access the memory as a type larger than a byte.

Answer (score 0):

The actual hex digits are being interpreted in a big-endian way, but the code looks like it's endianness-neutral, and should work regardless of your computer's endianness.

Comment: thanks. If that code is OK, I was also thinking how to "remove" the hex layer. e.g., if I want to directly store a decimal integer say 157 - how do I encode it in `sendBuffer` so that I can read it back also? I am also interested how to write normal string in device *without* hex, e.g., string like "Hello world" - but I may open a separate topic for this too...

Comment: Are you trying to send structured data, rather than just a bunch of bytes? If so, you should consider using something like [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: Hi Chris, no probably I will be just sending stuff like strings, e.g., "hello world" or integers

Comment: That _is_ structured data. In particular, if you want to send strings or integers and you expect the other side to know that it's a string or integer, there has to be some way to encode the type of the data inside the byte stream. That's what protocol buffers will do for you.

Comment: hmm... yes but I will send one type of data during one call, e.g., during one `send` call send only one `int`, at another send call send only one string. Why do I need these buffers? You can see above I didn't use them (hex example). I could also convert int --> hex and write it using method in my initial question (or convert string --> hex) - but I was thinking to avoid hex conversion ...... ps. Also, I am the "other side" I will be reading this data back

Comment: Even with hex, you're not really supposed to be sending structured data. I mean, with strings, do you have an encoding scheme to say how long the string is? If you're prepending a byte counter as one byte, what happens if your string is longer than 255 bytes? etc. Even if you're the other side, having to design a custom protocol for every message seems to be painful. It's easier to just use a system for structured messages and be done with it.

Comment: I can only *send and read*  multiple of 16 bytes, so I thought if my string e.g., "hello world" is not 16 bytes I could pad it with zeros say...(like its with hex). is this not okay?

Comment: Sure, each frame is 16 bytes, but in theory, by joining the frames up, you can have data as big as you like. Unless you're really trying to fit each message within one frame. In which case, good luck; 16 bytes really doesn't fit a lot.

Comment: Yes I was thinking if I have 28 byte string I would just pad it up to 32 and send it twice. Are we understanding each other correctly? Like I said, I think I could already use the method I posted in my question for this, e.g., take "Hello world" convert it to HEX - and then done, use the method from my question, isn't it?

Comment: >>> Chris Jester-Young wrote: " In particular, if you want to send strings or integers and you expect the other side to know that it's a string or integer, there has to be some way to encode the type of the data inside the byte stream". During reading, I **know** whether the data I read is int or string. It depends which block I read form my device, if I read block 1 I know I stored an int there etc...

Comment: Re your last example: assuming a block is the 16-byte unit you referred to, are you really going to use a whole block for sending just an int?!

Comment: Yes why not? this is smart card. Actually I may need to store just one int throughout whole application lifecycle sometimes. there is memory and it's not slow...

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young He keeps talking about "writing to a device", so he probably has to use a format which has been predefined by the device.