# embed int/string in byte array-storing

Tags: c++

I am writing some data to smart card.

You can look how this is done when I want to store a hex string on the card here: [Formatting and writing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904775/formatting-and-writing-data) - also from this post one can see that I don't have endiannes issues.

Given this, and given that usually data is stored on device like this:

```
unsigned char sendBuffer[20]; // This will contain the data I want to store + some header information

sendBuffer[0]=headerInfo;
sendBuffer[1]=data[0]; // data to store, byte array; should be 16 bytes or multiple of 16
sendBuffer[2]=data[1];
...
sendBuffer[16]=data[15];
```

Now, we invoke call: `Send(sendBuffer, length).` And done, `data` is written. How the data can be read back is also mentioned on the above link.

- I am interested, say now I want to store integer 153 (decimal) on the card, how I do this? (I think I must basically embed it in `sendBuffer` array-right?)
- Or if I want to store/send string: "Hello world 123xyz", how do I do this also?

ps. Also I am usually the receiver, I need to read data back. And depending on the memory block I read, I may in advance know whether I stored an int or string there.

Comment: @한국매미: I don't think I need serialization, why? look at the link I provided in question, there I write hex strings without serialization. If I want to store decimal 203 in my case I could also convert it to HEX and store it as I described on the link, but I was thinking to avoid this intermediary HEX conversion, and store directly int and string there

Comment: He's right. Serialization pretty much means "turn it into a string", because you can then write the string. Obviously, if you _already_ have a string, serialization is redundant.

Comment: @MSalters: Can you please provide more elaborate answer? I could not follow. I think I tried to give all the necessary information to make clear what situation I faced (including the link from my previous question).

Comment: @dmcr_code: You've already asked 5 rather basic questions, and now you can't follow rather elementary logic. It appears that you're just not experienced enough yet to pick up such problems. SO cannot substitute for school.

Comment: @MSalters: it's easy for you to say this. I already showed you working example with Hex string. I just think it is misunderstanding, people are not getting fully my situation ... I could already achieve what I want just by converting the decimal integer to hex and using method from the question I linked, isn't it?

Comment: @dmcr_code: Well, that's just another example where your lack of experience is showing. Computers don't store a decimal integer 153. Computers work in bits. So does your smartcard. Still, you keep asking about a conversion. Why?

Comment: @MSalters I think that because in his program he inputs the data in decimal. Earlier questions in this epic where about decimal to hex conversion.

Comment: @MSalters: I know computer stores data in bits. As john said just I have a decimal variable. My previous hex solution is working, just I was thinking to avoid HEX conversions, and write ints and strings directly in the buffer ..

Comment: @dmcr_code: Seriously, that's lesson 3 or so in a basic programming course. I wasn't being a smart-ass when I suggested school.

Comment: @MSalters: which is lesson 3? that computers store data in binary? believe me I know far more than that. Anyway, I think john managed to give me some good advice, which works, I will look more into that direction

Comment: @dmcr_code: No, that the conversion from human/decimal to computer/binary happens on I/O. Typical exercise for such a lesson: `std::cout << "what's your age?"<< std::endl; std::cin >> age;`. Entehr the age in decimal, it gets stored in binary. _That_ is the level of your problem.

Comment: @MSalters: I think I was just looking for a way how to copy int to byte array and also string to byte array. I know that numbers/everything on pc are stored in binary format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do seem to be making this more complicated than it needs to be. Because you don't have endianess issues reading or writing ints from your buffer is easy enough.

```
// writing
*(int*)(sendBuffer + pos) = some_int;

// reading
some_int = *(int*)(sendBuffer + pos)
```

`pos` is the offset in *bytes* in your `sendBuffer`.

To copy a string to or from the buffer I would just use `strcpy` if your string is nul terminated or `memcpy` if it isn't. E.g.

```
// writing
strcpy(sendBuffer + pos, some_string);

// reading
strcpy(some_string, sendBuffer + pos);
```

Obviously you have to be careful here that you have the available memory to store the strings.

Comment: thank you very much. I think you are on the right track .. I will try your suggestion

Comment: I like your solution with ints. It seems the compiler automatically extracts bytes from `some_int` and distributes them correctly accross `sendBuffer` right?

Comment: Yes, using the cast effectively tells the compiler to pretend that sendBuffer is an integer.

Comment: What to do if I want to write `float` instead of some_int?

Comment: Simple enough `*(float*)(sendBuffer + pos) = some_float;`, but again this makes the assumption that your target (card reader or whatever it is) uses the same floating point format as your compiler. Which may not be the case.

Comment: And if I want to write Unicode strings I'd probably use `wcscpy` and similar functions right? (plus take into account size is double now)...

Comment: what is the difference between your way of storing an int (using cast) and solution using bit shifts and & operator? (e.g., this one `buf[0] = src & 0xFF; buf[1] = (src >> 8) & 0xFF; buf[2] = (src >> 16) & 0xFF; buf[3] = (src >> 24) & 0xFF;`)

Comment: They are the same assuming there's no endianess issue, and assuming that an int is four bytes. The bit shift version explcitly puts the least significant byte first in `buf`, in the cast version it depends on the endianess of your architecture whether the least signifcant byte ends up first or last.

Comment: john, will the bit shift and & approach work correctly even if `src` (the integer) is say 6 bytes? but I "treat" it as a 4 byte int and also embed two numbers in the buffer? Like this: `buf[0] = src & 0xFF; buf[1] = (src >> 8) & 0xFF; buf[2] = (src >> 16) & 0xFF; buf[3] = (src >> 24) & 0xFF; buf[4] = src2 & 0xFF; buf[5] = (src2 >> 8) & 0xFF; buf[6] = (src2 >> 16) & 0xFF; buf[7] = (src2 >> 24) & 0xFF;)`

Comment: hm... really? So even if `src` and `src2` are 8 byte integers but I use above code, you think it will be ok? I was planning to ask a separate question on that now ..

Comment: @dmcr_code I didn't realise you had eight byte integers. If you have eight byte integers why not just use one integer? I think you may be overthinking this.

Comment: Hi john, thanks. Now I was thinking since on some platforms int is either 4 or 6 bytes. So I was thinking if the above code with shifts will also work for number which is 6 bytes (assuming my integer is never more than 4 bytes even if the sizeof type is actually 6)?

Comment: @dmcr_code Since integer size is crucial here I would switch to integers that specify their size. Instead of `int` use `int32_t` (a 32-bit or 4 byte integer), `int32_t` will be defined in header `<cstdint>`. But yes you're right, if the int is bigger than four bytes your code will still work.

Comment: thanks for `int32_t` tipp (hope it is also available on Linux). Yes, I meant if the **type** of `int` is 6 bytes but I know that integer inside the variable is always less than 4 bytes -- you meant that too?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I implemented your suggestion (as above) of writing ints using casting and used `int32_t` type, now I can successfully write and read three integers in my buffer consecutively, thanks. Do you think it is fine?

Comment: @john The first part of your answer is wrong, since it violates the strict aliasing rule.